# Play2 and Servlet Container

Tags: scala

Why Play is not supporting the Servlet technology by default. It is supporting Java but not servlet. why this? Is it not meant for Java guys working in Web application with servlets. I would like to develop web application in Scala and Play and deploy in a Servlet container without any workaround or hacking. If it is hard then I would prefer Scala and JSF. This will be the situation most of the java developers trying to adopt Scala.

Comment: _I would like to develop web application in Scala and Play and deploy in a Servlet container without any workaround or hacking._ If you find that using a plugin is acceptable for you, you could try the [play2-war-plugin](https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin).